# Property with name "id" not deserialized in mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am trying to fetch a record from the mongo db in c#

Data in the mongodb collection:

```
{
  id:0
  parameter:"Unscheduled Demand"
  remarks:"Formula Based"
  value:89
}
```

Issue: `id` property is not getting deserialized from the data in C#.

C# class structure:

```
public class children
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string parameter { get; set; }

    public string remarks { get; set; }

    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

This is the error that occurs:

> Element 'id' does not match any field or property of class children

Comment: Hi @Kailash thanks for your question. Do you remember if your class mapped to a MongoDB **collection**, or to some **subdocument** attached to a collection? Your class name `children` suggests to me it's a **subdocument**. For me, I encountered this issue when deserializing an array of **subdocuments** from MongoDb/BSON to my C# class -- my `public string id;` property was just empty string. If I used a different property name like `public string labelId;`, it could deserialize. Or if I used your `cm.MapProperty(c => c.id);` approach it could deserialize.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/ the `[BsonId]` attribute defines which field should be mapped for Mongo's `_id` element. If you want to use a field called "id" you should remove this tag

```cs
public class children
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string parameter { get; set; }

    public string remarks { get; set; }

    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

My guess is that without removing the attribute you will still be able to insert into Mongo, and see there is an `_id` set

Comment: Hi @Yonatan, 

Thanks for your suggestion

In addition to your suggestion i have also done the below in the startup class 

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<children>(cm =>
   {
    **cm.MapProperty(c => c.id);**
    cm.MapProperty(c => c.parameter);
    cm.MapProperty(c => c.remarks);
    cm.MapProperty(c => c.value);
   });
```

Comment: Did you add your actual `_id`? Maybe try adding `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]`

Comment: For me (maybe for @Kailash), the C# class represented a subdocument, not a document, so there was no need for an `_id` property because my C# class did not represent a collection per se; but subdocuments stored in an array on each of the documents in that collection. Still I think the C# driver's deserialization conventions caused me problems (my `id` property would have an empty string value). I had to use @Kailash's approach of `cm.MapProperty(c => c.id);` to get deserialization to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

We need to make manually identify the identity property as per the official mongodb documentation for C#

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/

**Changes Made**

**Previous Class Structure**

```
public class children
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string parameter { get; set; }

    public string remarks { get; set; }

    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

**Current Class Structure**

```
public class children
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int32)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string parameter { get; set; }

    public string remarks { get; set; }

    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

Additional Changes in

**Startup.cs**

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<children>(cm =>
            {
                cm.MapProperty(c => c.id);
                cm.MapProperty(c => c.parameter);
                cm.MapProperty(c => c.remarks);
                cm.MapProperty(c => c.value);
            });
```

**MAKING THE ABOVE CHANGES RESOLVED MY ISSUE**

These changes (specifically the `BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap`) are necessary to override the [conventions of C# serialization](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/1.11/serialization/#identifying-the-id-field-or-property) in  the "Identifying the Id Field or Property" section:

> **NOTE**
>
> The default conventions will discover a public property or field with the name `Id`, `id`, or `_id`. It is generally unnecessary to decorate this field with an attribute or map it explicitly.